# queue.close() "raises" BrokenPipeError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

Using python 3.7 on Unix, the following code:

```py
import multiprocessing

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue.put(1)
# time.sleep(0.01)  Adding this prevents the error
queue.close()
```

"raises" (in the background) a BrokenPipeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 242, in _feed
    send_bytes(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 404, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

To me this clearly looks like a bug, since `queue.close()` together with `queue.join_thread()` only exist to avoid that kind of bugs.
Am I missing something?

Notice that the BrokenPipeError is only raised in the background thread which is internally used by python to feed the queue, so from the main process point of view no error is raise and the "only" consequence is just spurious tracebacks printing.

(Also related to [multiprocessing.Queue fails intermittently. Bug in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680479/multiprocessing-queue-fails-intermittently-bug-in-python))

Comment: With Python 3.11 on macOS 13.0.1 your code (without the sleep) does not cause any issues. Maybe this was an issue in 3.7 that's been resolved in more modern versions

Comment: consider updating to python 3.10 or 3.11 where this bug is fixed, talking from windows point of view here.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Do you have a link to the Bug?

Comment: i don't think it was reported, but it certainly happens up to 3.9, but not in 3.10 or 3.11, and at this point you cannot get this fixed for any version below 3.10 because they have all reached end of bugfixes period, and only get security updates.

Comment: here is the issue https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91185

Comment: Indeed it is using python 3.7

Comment: @AhmedAEK your comment looks like an answer to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in python, it happens in 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9, it is resolved in python 3.10, and later versions.

This is a link to the issue [on cpython github](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91185)